# Is it possible to add a javascript variable into an escape_javascript statement?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, interpolation

I know this sounds insane. ;)

My Line :

```
"#{escape_javascript(content_tag(:a, "edit", :href => edit_object_payment_url(@object, "\#{payment_id}")))
```

Then with interpolation, I inject my variables. Payment_id is a javascript variable. Is it possible to syntactically pass that variable into this escaped_javascript statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Rails view won't have access to JavaScript variables, so you won't be able to call the Rails URL helper methods like `edit_object_payment_url` using JavaScript variables. But you could use JavaScript to construct the URL on the client side.

Comment: Is it then possible to perform a ternary expression within a javascript string interpolation?

Comment: Not sure about within interpolation, but you can do `"here's " + (x ? 'one' : 'a') + " string"`

Comment: I don't believe that's true. My code : `"<a href='objects/357/payments/"+ typeof payment_id === 'undefined' ? '357' : #{payment_id}  + "'>Delete</a>"` Still returns undefined variable `payment_id`

Comment: That's because, within an `<a>` element you're not executing JavaScript. There you are expected to be writing valid HTML, which doesn't support concatenating values with `+`, or interpolation for that matter. What you can do, though, is (within a `<script>`), run some JS code like this (using jQuery): `$('a#my_link').prop('href', 'objects/357/payments/' + payment_id);`